# Why won't React Native package upgrade to latest version?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-permissions

I'm using `react-native-permissions` in my React Native app, and according to [the docs](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-permissions) it's on version 3.3.1. I run `npm i react-native-permissions` and the version installed is 1.2.1. I'm on `react-native@0.63.4`. Does this prevent me from being able to get the most recent version of packages like `react-native-permissions`?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the version you want in package.json?